# How to write test case in Jest to handle rxjs 'delay' between two API calls

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, rxjs, timeout

I have a function with chained api calls. I have added rxjs `delay` between two API calls.

How to write test case in Jest to handle `delay` between two API calls.

Sequence of APIs

1. first API call
2. after `switchMap` call `delay` of `5000`.
3. Call Next API
4. `switchMap` further conditional code to check conditions

Comment: Please don't just dump all your code. Make an effort in removing the parts that are not essential to the question. If possible, create a minimal repro on Stackblitz. Keep in mind that if you don't make that effort initially, every person reading your question will have to make that effort for you, decreasing your chances to get an answer.

Comment: You have to use a combination of `fakeAsync` and `tick` to be able to handle the `delay` of 1 second. Here are two examples: https://baldur.gitbook.io/angular/angular-test/testing/using-fakeasync-to-test-async-observables and https://medium.com/@penghuili/angular-unit-test-usage-of-fakeasync-and-tick-f175e351d804.

Comment: Adding flush() at the end resolved my issue thanks @AliF50 Your solution helped me halfway.

Answer (score 0):

You need Timer Mocks.

https://testing-library.com/docs/using-fake-timers/

https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks

example:

```
describe('Test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
    jest.useRealTimers();
  });

  test('should add a message', () => {
    messageService.add(message);

    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: I am getting error "1 timer(s) still in the queue." after adding the timer solution.